# Using dplyr to filter all rows from one variable until another

Tags: r, dplyr

My data looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(
  value = runif(10)
  id = c("junk","start","1","2","end","morejunk","junk","start","4","end")
)
```

I want to use `filter()` to extract everything from the `id` `"start"` until the `id` `"end"`. The problem is the number of observations between the starting row and ending row vary, so I can't filter every x rows. Is there a way to use `filter()` in a way that I could specify `from = "start"` `until = "end"`?

Answer (score 1):

You can first identify where "start" and "end" are. Then using those pairwise of indices to index the data.frame. This assumes that there is a corresponding pair of start and end each time.

```
set.seed(0L)
data <- data.frame(
    value = runif(10),
    id = c("junk","start","1","2","end","morejunk","junk","start","4","end")
)
idx <- which(data$id %in% c("start", "end"))
lapply(split(idx, ceiling(seq_along(idx)/2)), function(x) data[x[1]:x[2],])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can

- use `which` to identify row indices with `"start"` and `"end"`,
- add and subtract 1 from each, respectively so as not to include those rows,
- pass those sequences to `:` in parallel via `Map`,
- `unlist` to simplify the list to a vector, and
- subset with `slice`

which leaves

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(47)

data <- data.frame(
    value = runif(10),
    id = c("junk","start","1","2","end","morejunk","junk","start","4","end")
)

data %>% slice(unlist(Map(`:`, 
                          which(.$id == 'start') + 1, 
                          which(.$id == 'end') - 1)))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>       value     id
#>       <dbl> <fctr>
#> 1 0.7615020      1
#> 2 0.8224916      2
#> 3 0.5433097      4
```

or in base,

```r
data[unlist(Map(`:`, 
                which(data$id == 'start') + 1, 
                which(data$id == 'end') - 1)), ]
#>       value id
#> 3 0.7615020  1
#> 4 0.8224916  2
#> 9 0.5433097  4
```

Comment: like your base solution

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. I didn't know about Map.